# Remove a field from a Sitecore template

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

I am currently working on a Sitecore project and we have a rather large template that has been around since the beginning of the project. As such, it has about three dozen or so fields that we no longer use.

Our current solution is to delete the template and recreate it. We haven't done that yet because we'd have to recreate all the objects based on this template (around 50) in the new template or try the arduous project of converting them over to the new template before deleting the one they are based on.

Is there a way to delete these unused fields from the template so we can avoid these messes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never mind. I figured it out just after posting.

In the tree elements for the fields you defined, right-click and delete. Simple as that.

Comment: Selecting the field, going to Builder Options and click Remove works as well :-)

Comment: Now you can run a database clean-up from the Control Panel > Database section. Running a clean-up will remove DB entries for fields that no longer exist on the template, thus reducing the DB size.

Comment: @MarkUrsino: Will running the clean up from the control panel also delete the template fields that are not referenced?

Comment: No because if its not referenced then there's nothing in the DB using it. A clean-up is not the same as removing a template field itself. It simply removes records that reference a foreign key (the field ID) for which an item (the field) no longer exists

Answer (score 1):

Also, you can just clear the field on the builder tab, save it, and it will delete the field as well.